# If condition not working properly and counter is not updating

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement

Hey in the below code even if the "if" condition is not true it prints the value in if statement.
how do i get to print "No matches found"

```
counter=0
print(": HOTEL NAME : ROOM NUMBER :  AIR CONDITIONING  : BREAKFAST  :  TELEVISION   : WIFI  : Cost/night($):")
for b in range(0,(n+2)):
    if(cost >= rooms1[b][6]):               
        print(rooms1[b])
        counter=1
ex=input("Press any key to continue..")
if(counter==0):
    print("No Hotels found accoeding to your budget")
    ex=input("Press any key to continue\n")
```

control is not going to the `if (counter==0)` even if the if statement is not true and counter is not set to 1.

```
if(counter==0):
    print("No Hotels found accoeding to your budget")
    ex=input("Press any key to continue\n")
```

Comment: Apparently the condition _is_ `True`. You may want to print its value or use a debugger to convince yourself.

Comment: We have no idea what data your program is working on - but my guess would be that counter == 0 - you need to use a debugger (or even ``print(counter)`` just before the if statement)..

Answer (score -1):

**Try it**

```
counter = 0

if counter == 0:
    print("No Hotels found accoeding to your budget")
    ex = input("Press any key to continue\n")
```

Comment: The answer is of no use, has no explanation and is not even formatted